# What is the difference between Ctrl-C and SIGINT?

Tags: unix, sigint, keyboardinterrupt

I have been debugging a Python program which segfaults after receiving a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception. This is normally done by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> from the shell. To test if a particular code change fixed the bug, I had a small shell-script that sent `SIGINT` to the program at random time after start-up. The problem I have is that sending <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> seems to have a different effect on the program than sending the signal `SIGINT` and is thus not causing the bug to appear, so I quite wonder what the difference is then between the two actions.

The program does not catch any keyboard actions at all, and is just a python program with some threads/processes in them. It installs no signal handlers (though Python does), and `stty -a` gives `intr = ^C`. I suspect it might be that <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> sends `SIGINT` to all the sub-processes/threads while `kill -INT` only sends to the primary process, but that is as far my suspicions go.

Here is the shell script which sends the `kill -INT`.

```sh
wait
while :; do
    seconds="$(python -c 'import random; print random.random()*4')"
    ./mandos --debug --configdir=confdir \
             --statedir=statedir --no-restore --no-dbus &
    pid=$!
    { sleep $seconds; kill -INT $pid; } &
    fg %./mandos
    status=$?
    if [ $status -gt 1 ]; then
        echo "Failed exit $status after $seconds seconds"
        break
    fi
    wait
done
```

Comment: I'm not sure how much of a difference this would be but its possible ctrl+c is sending `SIGTERM` instead of `SIGINT`. Also, when handling the exception are you cleaning up your sub-processes/threads correctly? The way python handles threads I don't believe it would seg-fault, but its probably possible with sub-processes.

Comment: <CTRL>+C can be configured, so check your `stty -a` settings, look for `intr = ^C`, maybe ^C is set for something else as well?

Comment: is there any multithreading in the code?

Comment: just saw that you said there were threads in your OP. I would say that could be your problem. The threads aren't being terminated correctly when the script receives the SIGINT.

Comment: Do you mean threads are effected if you do ctrl + C compared to sending the signal -INT? The reason I said threads is that Im using multiprocessing manager, and the way python implement it uses the threading library.

Comment: @Belorn : be carefull, despite the interfaces are similar, multiprocessing is not the same than threading. With multiprocess, python creates real processes, not threads.

Comment: You could always try to debug where the seg fault is: http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html If your using eclipse it should be easy to see where it seg faults and to see a stack trace on whats going on.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`^C` sends a `SIGINT` to all the processes in the foreground process group. To do the equivalent with `kill`, you should send the signal to the process group (OS-level concept):

```
kill -SIGINT -<pid>
```

or to the job (shell-level concept, the pipeline ended with `&`):

```
kill -SIGINT %
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for, but for unknown reasons the code still do not segfault when I use the automated script. I found the bug causing python to crash - python library multiprocessing is implemented with threads, and it causes segfaults in gobject if one do not call gobject.threads_init. Still, the original question for me is left as a mystery as why the manually invoked ctrl+c triggered the bug, but the automated script did not.

Comment: Sorry for being obtuse, but what does the '%' mean in this context?

Comment: @KevinCantwell: it refers to the current job, i.e. the last backgrounded job (either started in the background, or stopped while it was in the foreground, and thus backgrounded).

Comment: @ninjalj Am I correct in assuming that it is the shell that translates `^C` to `SIGINT` and then sends the latter to the processes in the foreground process group? Or does the Python interpreter partake in this process in any way?

Comment: @balu: SIGINT is handled by the line discipline, see termios(3) VINTR. See also stty(1) for the user level command to change line disciplinr settings. So, the shell just has to configure correctly the line discipline, and set the foreground process group with tcsetpgrp(3).

Comment: @ninjalj This is the first time I'm hearing of the term [*line discipline*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_discipline), so this was really helpful! Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Addendum: I've found https://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/ (section "An example") really helpful to understand where the line discipline enters the game on modern desktop systems.

Answer (score 9):

As [described here](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html) :

> Python installs a small number of signal handlers by default: SIGPIPE
>   is ignored (so write errors on pipes and sockets can be reported as
>   ordinary Python exceptions) and SIGINT is translated into a
>   KeyboardInterrupt exception. All of these can be overridden.

so, the behaviour should be the same between sending a SIGINT and a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>.

But, you have to be carefull with the `KeyboardInterrupt`, if somewhere in your code you've got a

```
try:
   ...
except:   # notice the lack of exception class
   pass
```

this will "eat" the KeyboardInterrupt exception.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. found one line doing that, and I think that will fix an unrelated bug. But even with that commented out, the primary issue with segfault is still there, and the more weird one that sending kill -INT do not trigger it but ctrl + c does.

Comment: I like this answer because it makes clear *where* exactly the translation between SIGINT and `KeyboardInterrupt` happens. As for your warning: For this reason I would always recommend using `try: ... except Exception: ...` as a catch-all for "normal" exceptions, so as to not accidentally catch unusual ones like `KeyboardInterrupt` and `SystemExit`, compare [link 1](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/exceptions.html#KeyboardInterrupt) and [link 2](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit).