# How to start a completely separated process with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For context, I'm trying to run this in a rails environment.

Basically, I have a rails app, and on a certain controller#action, a job will be spun up with ActiveJob, and in that job is where I want to run a shell script that I wrote.

The shell script just clones another repo containing a rails app into a different directory on the server, installs all required deps, **and then starts the server**.

So, that means at some point, there will be a **parent app** and a **child app** (or children apps)

This is what my `perform` method looks in the job:

```rb
  def perform(resource)
    fork { exec("#{Rails.root.to_s}/my_shell_script.sh #{resource.app_name}") }
  end
```

and this almost works, but the process isn't separated because `fork` inherits the parents terminal. So the child app's rails server will get started, but when I go to my terminal window for the parent app where `rails s` was ran, not only do I see logs for the child app, but when i kill the parent's server with `Ctrl-c` the child's server also get's killed.

I see two sets of closing messages because both servers are getting killed.

```
^C- Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
- Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
=== puma shutdown: 2021-02-06 14:47:46 -0700 ===
- Goodbye!
=== puma shutdown: 2021-02-06 14:47:46 -0700 ===
- Goodbye!
Exiting
Exiting
```

So my question is how do i separate these? I **do not** want to see the child app's logs in my server logs and if I kill the parent app's server, I want the child apps to continue to run. Basically, I want them to be completely separated.

#### What else I've tried

I tried using the `system` method since it creates a sub shell, but it's still not a completely separate process.

```
  def perform(resource)
    fork do
      system("#{Rails.root.to_s}/gensite.sh #{resource.app_name}")
    end
  end
```

Comment: Have you tried killing the parent manually with kill in the command-line ?

Comment: @VincentFourmond Wow, yes I just did and the child app is indeed still running. What does `Ctrl-c` do that `kill` doesn't? And beyond this, is there anyway to still avoid getting logs from my child app in my parent's app server logs? Thanks for responding

Comment: I'm not sure but I think if the child process is connected to the terminal, then both the parent and the child receive SIGINT when you hit Ctrl+C. Killing specifically the parent has no such problem.
The problem with the logs is that the log file that was open before forking still stays open to the same place. I'm not familiar enough with rails logging to work around this...

Comment: See there too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398845/what-is-the-difference-between-ctrl-c-and-sigint

Comment: What should happen when the server restarts? Should only the main application start automatically again? Or should all other "child" applications that were running start again too?

Comment: Have you tried using `nohup`?

Comment: @spickermann if the parent server restarts then only the parent server should restart. I want them completely separate

Comment: @AngelGarcia: I am sorry it did not think about a re-start of a server _process_ but about the restart of the whole _machine_.