# How to interrupt a Django Management Command

Tags: python, django, signals, interrupt-handling

I overrode BaseCommand to create my own management command, as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/). It's a long-running process though, and I want to be able to interrupt it and have it gracefully shut down when I send it ctrl+c.

I tried the usual signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler), but the signal_handler never gets called. Django seems to have its own [signal handling system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/), but I made responders for the three django.core.signals: got_request_exception, request_finished, and request_started but none of those get called either.

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/5789642/400691 ?

Comment: Django signals don't have anything at all to do with OS signals.

Comment: @meshy usually the [signal library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) works to catch the SIGINT signal that's raised by a ctrl+c.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks, I figured as much. Considering the amount of jargon one must familiarize themselves with to get acquainted with the Django platform, you think they'd come up with their own terminology for a completely different system sharing the same namespace. :)

Comment: Old question but actually standard python signal handling does work in management commands. Just checked it for python 3.5.1 and django 1.11.2.