# Send Ctrl+C from .sh script

Tags: bash, gatt

I am running hcitool application ($hcitool lescan). It detects all the bluetooth connected devices and shows the UUID for each. I press Ctrl+C when I see sensortag UUID B0:B4:48:BD:0F:83 and proceed. I want all this to be done using a .sh script. Please guide.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789642/how-to-send-controlc-from-a-bash-script

Comment: What have you tried until now? -- Sending the equivalent of a Ctrl+C from a script would be done with `kill -INT $pid`, where $pid is the process you want to send the signal to.

Comment: Clearly an xy question http://xyproblem.info/ , don't take it literally... Consider rephrasing the question. What do you want to happen?

Comment: I want to stop sensing for more devices once it detects the required one. I had tried bkill tilll now which didnt work,

Comment: How can I see the process ID. I tried giving kill -INT but not sure of the PID.

Answer (score 2):

`grep` can quit immediately when a pattern is found:

```
hcitool lescan | grep -q 'B0:B4:48:BD:0F:83'
```

Answer (score 0):

kill -INT process_ID

CTRL + C sends a SIGINT signal. kill also does the same. So, just pass the process ID to the above command.

To get the PID(process ID) type command : 
pgrep foo(suppose foo is your process)

Comment: Grepping for processes is generally a bad idea, what if there are two or more processes running? Surely you don't want to kill someone else's process....