# how to send SIGINT to a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am writing a daemon with more than one process. once the first process is complete then it stops and needs mannual interrupt SIGINT(CTRL + C). 
After this next script is run.

Process 1 ended successfully.

How can add a SIGINT to proceed it further automatically ?

The question may be trivial but could only find how can we trap a given signal in a script, but how do we add one after completion of a task ?

Comment: Use `kill -2 $pid` to send `SIGINT`

Comment: @anubhava AFAIK the signal numbers aren't portable, but `kill -INT $pid` also works.

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789642/how-to-send-controlc-from-a-bash-script is a better duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

You can kill the current bash shell and all of its children with the command `kill -TERM -$$`.

Edit:

If, for example, you are launching processes like:

```
process1 &
process2 &
process3 &
process4
```

To modify it so that when any process ends it kills all the others you can use:

```
( process1 ; kill -TERM -$$ ) &
( process2 ; kill -TERM -$$ ) &
( process3 ; kill -TERM -$$ ) &
process4 ; kill -TERM -$$
```

Comment: This appears to answer a different question than what is being asked here.

Comment: @tripleee, His question isn't very clear, but I've updated my answer with more details about the exact situation that I'm solving.