# Cannot exit from docker logs -f <container> in jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, docker-run, docker-logs

By adding this command `docker logs -f <container>`, able to print the docker logs, but it is not exiting from this command after the server is running. I have other commands that have to be run after the docker run, but the logs command is not exiting.
We can exit the terminal in local, but how can I exit this and run the remaining shell script in jenkins pipeline automatically.
Also, tried  `docker logs -f --until=30s <container>`, but this is not even printing the logs in jenkins pipeline.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but if you add `-f` , which stands for _follow_, docker will keep trying to show new logs (follow the log output) until the container is completed (terminated, if you may). 
Could you clarify why `docker logs <container>` (a 1-time shot showing of logs) is not suitable?

Comment: @BorrajaX So, when I'm using just the ```docker logs <container>```, it's not showing me the whole indepth logs - like server ready at..., etc. adding the follow option is helpful for this.
Is there any other way I can terminate executing the ```docker logs -f <container>``` in the shell script itself?

Comment: Not that I know of. Maybe there is (I'm not super knowledgeable in Docker, to be honest) If it was me, I would maaaybe try to find a way to send a `kill -SIGINT`  to the `docker logs -f` process. [Like shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789642/how-to-send-controlc-from-a-bash-script). But that sounds like a terrible idea